# Too many events that are close to each other in time don't look good in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a problem with FullCalendar. The problem is that I have lots of short events that are close to each other in time, and even though I turned off overlapping of events, it just simply doesn't look good in the agendaWeek and agendaDay views:

[image: agendaWeek view]

I would like to achieve the same as in month view, where the events are listed one below the other and the row height is automatically enlarged:

[image: month view]

Is there a way to do this somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a similar demo in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjn7668z/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Agenda Views, thinking about how drag and drop, resize, select, and other actions you can perform in fullCalendar work, it all comes down to fullCalendar knowing the exact relationship between pixel location in the y-axis and the corresponding value in time relative to the day in question. This is because of a difference in how events are placed in agenda views compared to basic (like month view.) In agenda views, it appears as though events are being placed in a table with time slots as the rows and days as the columns. In reality, fullCalendar places events ABOVE this graphical representation of a table, not in it. The time slots are fixed based on your initialization options. Stacking events and changing the slot size would be breaking the rules that everything is based on which why i don't think we see it as an option. If you poke around the DOM of fullCalendar in agendaWeek and look at where events are placed, you'll see what i mean.

If it is common that slots get extremely busy in detail views, perhaps increasing the slot duration is an option? Another route is not using agenda views and sticking to unslotted timelines like in month view.